# ConstraintLayout - Adjust the view margins

Tags: android, view, margins, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to use the new features of how to build a layout in `ConstraintLayout` in **Android Studio 2.2**.

When I try to use Adjust the view margins nothing happens. Margins are not added to any `View`, neither of these that I have already added or those which I would like to add.

The margins change only when I change the parameters InControl the margin for each view in the Properties window for every `View` individually. Have you already used this feature?

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image: Screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The margin value in the toolbar applies to newly created connections (with the exception of connections to the parent). It's also the value we use when you use some of the placement tools (spread, etc.).